# Font Awesome blank squares in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, font-awesome

I'm migrating my website to another hosting, but I have problem with the font.
When you open site for the first time font is not working, it's just showing blank squares, after you go into any subpage it starts to works. Do you have any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Open your browser's inspector and look at the font's URL. It sounds like the homepage doesn't fully qualify the font file location but the subpage does, and then it's in cache so the homepage can use it.

Comment: Homepage seems to qualify where font is.

Comment: rafal86.hs1.linux.pl take a look on it

Answer (score 0):

its depends on where you added font awesome in opencart.

Mostly it should be in

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl
```

And if you added with some custom condition then check it.

because in opencart only Except then home page, other inner pages open with Query parameter.

ex. `index.php?route=common/home`

So, for inner pages check source code and look at the CSS path is proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add (I cannot comment), if you're not using the default theme, you'd want to navigate to catalog/view/theme/(your theme name)/template/common/header.tpl

If you're using the Journal theme, you'll want to check the template/journal2/headers folder.

Comment: I have no theme, this font used to work on my old hosting

Answer (score 0):

Try these and tell us if any of them makes a difference:

1. Edit your **config.php** and check that the `HTTP_SERVER` and `HTTPS_SERVER` variables are correct.
2. Make sure that the link to Font Awesome is correct, this also means making sure that if your site mainly uses **www.domain.com** and not **domain.com** that your link to Font Awesome has **www.** in as well. Same goes for **http://** vs **https://** and vice versa.
3. Check the casing of the font filename. **Font-Awesome.min.css** is not the same as **font-awesome.min.css** and your new server may care about that.

Koda